# How to easily convert .sdf developed in Vs 2010 to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I don't have SQL Server installed my machine. Hence I decided to start working with a SQL Server Compact Edition (`.sdf`) in VS2010. After then I installed SQL Server at the moment, now I'd like to convert from `.sdf` to a "real" SQL Server database.

How can I do it ? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should to is to change your `connectionString` that points to your Compact SQL to your new SQL Server instance.
After that in you Context file, inside of a static constructor which is called:

```
static YourDbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDbContext>());
}
```

This should create your database and tables based on your models. If you need to insert any data you should `Enable-Migrations` and in a configuration file that is createdc8 override `Seed` method.

One important thing **DO NOT ASSUME** that you have rights or privileges to CREATE or DROP DATABASE or to execute  table modificiations.

I will assume that you used EF Code First approach. Your context file could look something like this:

```
public YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    static YourDbContext()
    {
        // Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null); // Change this line to the next one
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDbContext>());
    }

    // The rest of implementation 
}
```

Inside of Visual Studio in `Package Manager Console` execute:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName YourProjectName
```

(If you have more than one DbContext implementation you will need to follow the instructions from the error message that Enable-Migrations throws back at you.)

Once this is done you will notice a  new folder `Migrations` with one file `Configuration.cs`. Open it and you will see method Seed.

```
protected override void Seed(YourDbContext context)
{
    //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
     //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
    //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
    //
    //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
    //      p => p.FullName,
    //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
    //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
    //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
    //    );
    //

    // Here you can call your context.DbSetImplementation.Add(new Something {...});
}
```

That's about it.

Comment: It sounds interesting. I'd like to work on and let u know the status. Thanks @husein-roncevic.

Comment: I've a few queries, by default i couldn't see the static constructor. Do i want to create?  I'd like to copy the data, can you explain more about migration steps ?